# Upgrade android version in Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-version

I have created a project in Eclipse with Android 4.0.3 platform, but when I run it on device with android 4.1.2, it doesn't work well. I don't know exactly what causes it, but I want to try to upgrade the project (in Eclipse) to android v.4.1.2. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: what is the problem facing

Comment: my app is integrated with web, so on the first run we should give the url of the web, then we can do the login activity. But when i test it in device with android 4.1.2, i can't login anymore. Always shows error message : password doesn't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple - find file called `project.properties` and replace this line:

```
target=android-15
```

to:

```
target=android-16
```

(API 15 is Android 4.0.3, API 16 is Android 4.1.2).

Comment: thank you! but, is there any program code should be changed as well?

Comment: not really. you might want to edit `AndroidManifest.xml` to set minimum and target SDK versions - in general, your version in project.properties should match one in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 2):

- Right click on your project
- Click Properties
- Android
- Select your new build target.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Build Target for your project at any time , Right-click the project in the Package Explorer, select Properties, select the Android and then check the desired Project Target.